# program to print the square pattern for the given N number of rows (numbers to be odd numbers)

Tags: java, square

I have tried as per below code but not able to get the desired output

```
package patterns;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OddSquarePattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int i=1;

        while(i<=n) {
            int j=n;
            int odd= 2*i-1;
            while(j>=i){
                System.out.print(odd);
                odd=odd+2;
                j--;
            }
            
            int p=1;
            while (p<=i-1) {
                System.out.print(p);
                p=p+2;  
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            i++;
                    
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For N = 4 in square pattern
1357
3571
5713
7135

Answer (score 1):

You should import scanner package. Type this in previous line before public static void
import java.util.Scanner;

Answer (score 1):

for successfully getting output as
N=5
output will be

```
13579
35791
57913
79135
91357
```

Code in Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    int i = 1,j;
    while(i<=N){
        int odd = 2*i-1;
        j=N;
        while(j>=i){
            System.out.print(odd);
            odd = odd +2;
            j--;
        }
        j = 1;
        int  p =1;
        while(j<=i-1){
            
            System.out.print(p);
            p= p+2;
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int i=1;

        while(i<=n) {
            int j=n;
            int odd= 2*i-1;
            while(j>=i) {
                System.out.print(odd);
                odd=odd+2;
                j--;
            }
            if(j!=0) {
                int p=1,temp=1;
                while (temp<i) {
                    System.out.print(p);
                    p=p+2;
                    temp++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write your code here
         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int i=1;

        while(i<=n) {
            int j=n;
            int odd= 2*i-1;
            while(j>=i){
                System.out.print(odd);
                odd=odd+2;
                j--;
            }
            
            int p=1;
            int k =1;
            while (k<=i-1) {
                System.out.print(p);
                p=p+2;  
                k++;
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int i=1;

        while(i<=n) {
            int j=1;
            int num=2*i-1;
            
            while(j<=n-i+1){
                System.out.print(num);
                num=num+2;
                j++;
            }
            
            j=1;
            int k=1;
            while(j<=i-1){
                System.out.print(k);
                k=k+2;
                j++;
            }
            
            
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestingoddSquare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            if(n>=0 && n<=50) {
            int i=1;
            while(i<=n) {
                int j=n;
                int odd= 2*i-1;
                while(j>=i){
                    System.out.print(odd);
                    odd=odd+2;
                    j--;
                }
                
                int p=1;
                int k=1;
                while (p<=i-1) {
                    System.out.print(k);
                    k=k+2; 
                    p=p+1;
                }
                
                System.out.println();
                i++;
                        
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=s.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            int odd=2*i-1;
            for(int j=n;j>=i;j--) {
                System.out.print(odd);
                odd=odd+2;
            }
            int p=1;
            for(int j=1;j<=i-1;j++) {
                System.out.print(p);
                p=p+2;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int i=1
    
    while (i<=n) {
        int j = n;
        int p = 2*i-1;
        while(j>=0){
            System.out.print(p);
            p=p+2;
            if(p>(2*n)-1) {
                p=1;
            }
            j--;
            }
    System.out.println();
    i++;
    }
    }   
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
public class Patterrn {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int i=1;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        int x=2*i-1;
        int j=1;
        while(j<=n)
        {
            if(x<=7)
            {
                System.out.print(x);
                x=x+2;
            }
            else
            {
                x=1;
                System.out.print(x);
                x=x+2;
            }
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        i++;
        x=x+2;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that takes an integer n as input and generates a square pattern of n x n size.

Input Format
The input consists of a single integer n, where 1 <= n <= 100.

Output Format
The output is a square pattern of size n x n, where each row consists of n asterisks (*).

Sample Inputs & Outputs
Sample Input 1
5
Sample Output 1

---

---

---

---

---

Constraints
1 <= n <= 100

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).